# How to get the conjugate symmetry of the complex matrix using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to get the conjugate symmetric of the complex matrix using matlab

Comment: Look at the transpose operator [link][http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html]

Comment: Please try to provide more information when asking questions, additional context and examples will result in better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is off-topic, but:

```
At = A';
```

`At` is the conjugate transpose of `A`.